# How to create custom soap fault message using spring web service

Tags: spring-ws

I'm trying to write a web service using spring web service library. I'm able to configure my endpoints successfully and it is working fine, but I'm facing some issues with the exception mappings.

I'm able to map exceptions using @SoapFault and SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver but the wsdl definition is as follows

```
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://abc.com/soap/">
    <xsd:complexType name="ServiceException">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="message" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="ValidationException">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="tns:ServiceException">
                <xsd:sequence/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="InternalException">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="tns:ServiceException">
                <xsd:sequence/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="AuthenticationException">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="tns:ServiceException">
                <xsd:sequence/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="LoginInput">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="UserName" nillable="false" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PassWord" nillable="false" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="LoginOutput">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ValidTo" nillable="false" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="login" type="tns:LoginInput"/>
    <xsd:element name="loginResponse" type="tns:LoginOutput"/>

    <xsd:element name="ValidationException" type="tns:ValidationException"/>
    <xsd:element name="InternalException" type="tns:InternalException"/>
    <xsd:element name="AuthenticationException" type="tns:AuthenticationException"/>
</xsd:schema>

<message name="LoginRequest">
    <part name="login" element="tns:login"/>
</message>

<message name="LoginResponse">
    <part name="loginResponse" element="tns:loginResponse"/>
</message>

<message name="ValidationException">
    <part name="ValidationException" element="tns:ValidationException"/>
</message>

<message name="InternalException">
    <part name="InternalException" element="tns:InternalException"/>
</message>

<message name="AuthenticationException">
    <part name="AuthenticationException" element="tns:AuthenticationException"/>
</message>

<portType name="ServicePortType">
    <operation name="Login">
        <input message="tns:LoginRequest"/>
        <output message="tns:LoginResponse"/>
        <fault name="ValidationException" message="tns:ValidationException"/>
        <fault name="InternalException" message="tns:InternalException"/>
        <fault name="AuthenticationException" message="tns:AuthenticationException"/>
    </operation>
</portType>

<binding name="ServiceBinding" type="tns:ServicePortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="Login">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn://Service#Login"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </output>
        <fault name="ValidationException">
            <soap:fault name="ValidationException" use="literal"/>
        </fault>
        <fault name="InternalException">
            <soap:fault name="InternalException" use="literal"/>
        </fault>
        <fault name="AuthenticationException">
            <soap:fault name="AuthenticationException" use="literal"/>
        </fault>
    </operation>
</binding>
```

How can I write a exception handling for this service definition?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some more search I found [this from spring source forum](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-29505.html).

```
SoapMessage response = (SoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse();
SoapBody soapBody = response.getSoapBody();

SoapFault soapFault =
soapBody.addClientOrSenderFault(ex.getMessage(), Locale.ENGLISH);

SoapFaultDetail faultDetail = soapFault.addFaultDetail();
Result result = faultDetail.getResult();

// My detail XML object
InvalidArgumentFault fault = new InvalidArgumentFault();
fault.setErrorCode("Custom Error Code");
fault.setOpsMessage("This is the ops message");
fault.setSystemMessage("This is the system message");

// Marshal the detail. We have to use the ObjectFactory which isn't
// marshaller agnostic because the detail element doesn't have an
// XmlRootElement tag as required by JAXB.
ObjectFactory of = new ObjectFactory();
mMarshaller.marshal(of.createInvalidArgumentFault( fault), result);
```

**UPDATED**

This a complete sample implementations I'm using,

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.transform.Result;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.oxm.Marshaller;
import org.springframework.ws.context.MessageContext;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.AbstractEndpointExceptionResolver;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapBody;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapFault;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapFaultDetail;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessage;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class CustomSoapFaultDetailAnnotationExceptionResolver extends
        AbstractEndpointExceptionResolver implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static Log log = LogFactory
            .getLog(CustomSoapFaultDetailAnnotationExceptionResolver.class);

    private Collection<Marshaller> marshallers;

    private Map<Class<? extends Object>, Marshaller> marshallerMap = new HashMap<Class<? extends Object>, Marshaller>();

    public CustomSoapFaultDetailAnnotationExceptionResolver() {
        setWarnLogCategory(getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean resolveExceptionInternal(MessageContext messageContext,
            Object endpoint, Exception ex) {
        boolean resolved = false;

        try {
            CustomSoapFaultDetails annotation = ex.getClass().getAnnotation(
                    CustomSoapFaultDetails.class);
            if (annotation != null) {

                Method m = ex.getClass().getMethod("getFaultInfo",
                        new Class[] {});
                Object fault = m.invoke(ex, new Object[] {});

                SoapMessage response = (SoapMessage) messageContext
                        .getResponse();
                SoapBody soapBody = response.getSoapBody();

                SoapFault soapFault = soapBody
                        .addClientOrSenderFault(
                                StringUtils.isBlank(ex.getMessage()) ? "server exception"
                                        : ex.getMessage(), Locale.ENGLISH);

                SoapFaultDetail faultDetail = soapFault.addFaultDetail();
                Result result = faultDetail.getResult();

                if (marshallerMap.containsKey(fault.getClass())) {
                    marshallerMap.get(fault.getClass()).marshal(fault, result);
                    resolved = true;
                } else {
                    for (Marshaller marshaller : marshallers) {
                        try {
                            marshaller.marshal(fault, result);
                            marshallerMap.put(fault.getClass(), marshaller);
                            resolved = true;
                            break;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // Ignore error
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.toString(), e);
        }
        return resolved;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
        this.marshallers = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(Marshaller.class)
                .values();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you pulling the `mMarshaller` from?

Comment: @Mark, I've updated the answer. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: I was hoping you managed to fish it out of the `MessageEndpoint` somewhere, but ultimately I dependency inject it as you do.

Comment: @Mark, I checked that possibility, but didn't find a way to do it. Please let me know if you find a way to do it.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Could you please show `CustomSoapFaultDetails` ?

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully used SOAP Spring-WS to create a web service.  Now I was doing the fault implementation in this SOAP service and I was able to do it with a class that I created like the following,

```
public class ServiceSoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver extends SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver
```

and inside the following overridden function,

```
@Override


protected void customizeFault(Object endpoint, Exception ex, SoapFault fault) {

//code for adding fault details

    SoapFaultDefinition soapFaultDefinition = new SoapFaultDefinition();
    String ENVELOPE_NAMESPACE_URI = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";

    //      soapFaultDefinition.setFaultStringOrReason("--" + ex);

    //      soapFaultDefinition.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

    QName CLIENT_FAULT_NAME = new QName(ENVELOPE_NAMESPACE_URI,"5003", "e");
    soapFaultDefinition.setFaultCode(CLIENT_FAULT_NAME);
    setDefaultFault(soapFaultDefinition);
    Result result = fault.addFaultDetail().getResult();

        // marshal
        try {
             JAXBContext.newInstance(ExceptionListType.class).createMarshaller().marshal(exceptionList, result);

}
```

Please [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395104/soap-spring-ws-how-to-customise-faultcodesoapenvserver-faultcode-to-fault/32493798#32493798) for the original solution.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for updating.  In the future, to avoid down votes (wasn't me), be sure to include the relevant details from the start.  Thanks!