# Implementing XSD's Exception Classes in Spring Web Service (SOAP)

Tags: spring-boot, soap, jax-ws, spring-ws

I'm creating a SOAP web service in Spring Boot using Spring WS.  The service I am recreating is a clone of a Service running on older technology which uses JavaX JWS, with the classes generated from an XSD.

The issues I have are linked/the same really:
1. I can't seem to 'receive' Exceptions thrown in the 'new' Web Service back to the consumer.
2. When querying the endpoint in SOAPUI, the Exception class for the Web Service appears as if it is a one-way method.

I believe this is because Spring WS isn't correctly implementing/understanding the Exception classes.

When an exception is thrown in the new service, the consumer receives a `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException`, rather than the Exception thrown in the Web Service.

The original JavaX service returns (using `TestException` as an example):

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Test</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns2:TestException xmlns:ns2="http://test.co.uk/">
               <code>abc123</code>
               <message>Test</message>
            </ns2:TestException>
         </detail>
      </S:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I can't find any documentation or guidance on how the exception should be build/configured to produce the same `<ns2>` nested element.  Is there a way to accurately pass the exception back so that it appears the same as it would in the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some examples of implementing custom exception resolver which extends AbstractEndpointExceptionResolver and defines SOAP fault mapping for different exception types: [example 1](https://maarten.mulders.it/2018/07/custom-soap-faults-using-spring-ws/), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4123880/2792888), [example 3](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-ws-add-detail-soapfault-exception-handling/).

Comment: Thanks - I had seen the Maarten Mulders guide (the other two are too old to be implementable these days), and it took a while but finally have it working.  He had used 'example' class names that were the same as common libraries which threw me off!